# How to get an USB keypad (numpad) working alongside with the main keyboard without the main keyboard writing numbers?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, numlock, numpad

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a netbook and when connecting a **USB numeric keypad**, and activate the **Num Lock** function, the letters on the **main keyboard** also works as numbers (I mean, U is 4, I is 5, O is 6, etc).  Does anyone know if there is a posibility to get it to work without altering the key functions on the main keyboard in order to do the numbers with the **usb keypad** and the writing with **main keyboard** without having to press **Num Lock** all the time to change between one and the another?
PS: In the same netbook running Chrome OS it works fine without num lock activated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My USB keyboard on Ubuntu 20.04 Gnome does not change the numlock state on the main keyboard (without a keypad).

Comment: When I activate the num lock on either the usb keypad or in the main keyboard they both lights get on or of and both keyboards changes their working state, what I would like to do is to make they work differently one from the another.

Answer (score 2):

You need to decouple them. Run

```
$ xinput
```

That's the list of input devices. You'll see a master (Virtual core keyboard) and your two keyboards attached to it.

Add a new master:

```
$ xinput create-master myOtherKeyboard
```

If you list them again you will see something like:

```
 myOtherKeyboard pointer id=21  [master pointer  (22)]
    ↳ myOtherKeyboard XTEST pointer id=23   [slave  pointer  (21)]
 myOtherKeyboard keyboard id=22 [master keyboard (21)]
    ↳ myOtherKeyboard XTEST keyboard id=24  [slave  keyboard (22)]
```

Now you have to move your other keyboard from the old shared master to the one you just created.

Note the `id=` fields. Get the numbers for  "myOtherKeyboard keyboard" (id=ID1)  and for you second keyboard (id=ID2) and reattach the keyboard to the new master:

```
$ xinput reattach ID2 ID1
```

The numlock keys should now be independent.

You will notice two pointer, because the master always have a keyboard and a pointer. Find the id=ID3 of the extra one (myOtherKeyboard pointer) and disable it:

```
$ xinput disable ID3
```

Comment: Hello @eduardo-trápani, thanks for answering, I followed the instructions and It works all right until I have to disable the second pointer, then it stops working the whole keypad. (I disable 19 as I get an error whien disabling 21
There is also a way to make this changes permanent? As when I disconnect the keypad or close session changes are lost.
Thanks in advance.

⎡ myOtherKeyboard pointer                  id=19 [master pointer  (20)]
⎜   ↳ myOtherKeyboard XTEST pointer            id=21 [slave  pointer  (19)]
⎣ myOtherKeyboard keyboard                 id=20 [master keyboard (19)]